# Problem copying files from hard disk to flash drive (USB)

Tags: files, usb

I'm trying to copy some files to my USB (5 GB). At the start its go fast (200 MB/s approx), but when it is en 3GB approx the speed begins to decrease (17 MB/s). It is always in the same place at 3gb, i use other usb port but it has the same problem.

Someone with this problem? a possible fix ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an issue. A drive will slow down during the transfer process and this is due to many factors. Between caching, heat, and other operations, you'll see a fast transfer dip into an average one. (5GB is pretty considerable for a typical flash drive.)

Here's a more detailed breakdown, worded much better than I probably could. https://superuser.com/a/315145

Comment: how can this not be an issue? I am unable to copy large files and never had that problem using windows.

Comment: What filesystem are you using? If it's something like exFAT, it could take a rather extensive amount of time to complete writes onto removable flash media.